# Accessing paragraph indent in ConTeXt: \parindent?

Tags: indentation, context, parindent

In ConTeXt, how do I access the value of the paragraph indent? With LaTeX, I can use `\parindent` and it seems to work also with ConTeXt, but from the [ConTeXt Garden's entry on indentation](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Indentation) I get the impression that this is not best practice.

What I ultimately want to do is reuse the indent in a custom start/stop environment. Like so:

```
\definestartstop[letter][
   style=italic,
   before={\blank[line]
      \setupnarrower[left=\parindent, right=\parindent]
      \startnarrower[left,right]
      \noindent},
   after={\stopnarrower
      \blank[line]}]
```

Comment: If you're only reading (not writing) it, using `\parindent` seems fine to me